# Как программно управлять частотой и памятью на видеокарте как в MSI afterburner?

Tags: c#, c++, nvidia, элементы-управления, msi

Как на с# или C++ реализовать управление памятью и частотой на видеокарте как в программе MSI afterburner? [image: MSI afterburner] Рыл библиотеки cudafy и CUDA от NVIDIA под c++, нашел только считывание имеющихся данных.

Answer (score 0):

Это скорее как подсказка, ибо такое не реализовывал.
В BIOS можно как раз гнать компоненты компьютера, значит в BIOS'е уже есть  "выходы" на компоненты.
Соответственно, если это возможно, тебе надо узнать к чему BIOS подключается у видеокарты и воплотить в виде кода.

Comment: Это тянет максимум на комментарий, но не на ответ